# Redirect a RTMP Request

Tags: redirect, streaming, rtmp

Is it possible to issue a redirect to a `rtmp` request - similar to a http 302 redirect?
It is not possible for me to fix all of the `rtmp` urls that exist in my content, so I would like to put some sort of a basic redirector in place that will send requests to my new server.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no such concept in RTMP. You will need the client to connect to an endpoint to query what URL to broadcast to.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/645#issuecomment-118998967 
 https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/blob/master/ngx_rtmp_notify_module.c#L1032

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understood you completely but I think I can help you a little bit and go on clarifying with comments. For example, I don't know if you have different entry points or just distribute 1->N.

> Your proposal, if I didn't misunderstand, is that you have an RTMP
>   traffic as input of a *basic redirector*, and wants to send the same
>   content to a list of RTMP addresses placed for example in a text file.
>   Your question is how to implement this *basic redirector*, isn't it?

In that case, you could do it with FFmpeg application, in the same way streaming systems send data to multi-publishing points (CDN for distribution)

File: **rtmp_output_list.txt**

```
rtmp://001.entrypoint.your_cloud.com/live/your_name?user=your_user&pass=your_pass
rtmp://002.entrypoint.your_cloud.com/live/your_name?user=your_user&pass=your_pass
rtmp://003.entrypoint.your_cloud.com/live/another_name?user=another_user&pass=another_pass
...
```

Bash script calling ffmpeg: **basic_redirector.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash for RTMP_OUTPUT in `cat rtmp_output_list.txt` 
RTMP_INPUT="rtmp://192.168.0.101/test"
METADATA="-metadata width=XXX -metadata height=XXX ... [rest of metadata]"
do
    ffmpeg -i $RTMP_INPUT -async 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy $METADATA -f megts -f flv $RTMP_OUTPUT 
done
```

If I didn't understand you correctly, please, comment and I'll help you.
Good luck.

Comment: Your example doesn't redirect anything, it's proxying the streams.  What I need is for when a streaming source tries to publish a stream to an RTMP server, it tells that streaming source to publish to a different server instead.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the difference between proxy and redirect. In my opinion it's not possible, because RTMP PUSH doesn't depend on what you implement in the middle, just in source, and RTMP PULL doesn't depend on what you implement in the middle, just in destination. 
So, if you want to redirect, you have to modify source who ingest video to your system. Otherwise I don't know why doing proxy with connection is not useful for you.

Comment: Apparently this is possible in Flash Media Server, so it's likely possible generically to some extent:  https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/645#issuecomment-118998967